# When sharing confidential information, which is more secure share via Outlook vs store on Sharepoint then provide access?

Tags: confidentiality, microsoft, outlook

I'm trying to figure out what is good practice and what is more secure for my small team.

I wanted to set a standard or governance on how to share confidential information within our team. One person is saying Outlook is just as secure as SharePoint, another person is saying SharePoint is far more secure and reliable.

I tried to do a little research on which is more secure or if it matters whether you store it on SharePoint and share it from there or if you send the files directly through Outlook from your PC (with End-Point Antivirus security installed) but I wasn't getting much information on it.

I know Outlook and SharePoint are two completely different pieces of software however I'm just looking for the most secure path in sharing confidential information?

Comment: An external store would let you revoke access at any moment, whereas if you've already emailed something, the recipient has it forever. It's also often nice to have everyone access the same copy if you have different versions; versioning over email is a nightmare.

Comment: That is a great point that I totally overlooked. Thanks Dandavis, I appreciate it, that basically settles it. Can you post that as an answer and I'll mark it. thanks